# Microphone array not working in Telegram

Tags: windows, audio, microphone, windows-11, telegram-messenger

I have an issue with the Telegram app on windows 11.  For some reason, when I use the microphone in the app, the sound seems to be coming out of a bucket, and is hardly comprehensible. I have a Huawei laptop with the latest drivers:

[image: Screenshot of microphone driver properties]

The interesting thing is that all the other apps work fine with these microphones, including the web version of Telegram.

How can I fix this? I have already checked everything for updates, reinstalled the app several times, including the version from the microsoft store, nothing helps.

Comment: Did Telegram support have anything to say about it? It sounds like their problem.

Comment: @Tetsujin I wish lol, they are not responding :)